# ¿No encuentra la url?

Tags: php, laravel, rutas, cpanel

Buenas, cargue mi página web al cpanel, pero solo me carga la página principal pero cuando ingreso a otra ruta me apare error.

Al cargar la página me encuentro con esta vista que esta perfecta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar click en cualquier a nosotros o menú me cargue con el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrian ayudar con este problema. mis rutas son:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function()
{
    route::get('/','Principal\principal@inicio');
    route::get('nosotros','Principal\principal@nosotros');
    route::get('menu','Principal\principal@menu');
    // route::get('contacto','Principal\principal@contacto');
    // route::get('clientes','Principal\principal@cliente');
    route::get('cursos','Principal\principal@cursos');
    route::get('administracion','Admin\administracion@sesion');

});
```

y el controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Principal;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class principal extends Controller
{
    public function inicio()
    {
        return view('Principal/inicio');
    }

    public function nosotros()
    {
        return view('Principal/nosotros');
    }

    public function menu()
    {
        return view('Principal/menu');
    }

    public function contacto()
    {
        return view('Principal/contacto');
    }

    public function cliente()
    {
        return view('Principal/clientes');
    }

     public function cursos()
    {
        return view('Principal/cursos');
    }
}
```

Comment: crea una maquina virtual y tu problema se solucionara

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que no está el `mod_rewrite` de apache o falte el archivo `.htaccess` en public. Revisalo, por que esta saltando el 404 por defecto de apache la primera finciones por qué no tiene que reescribir nada. ¿Qué versión de Laravel estas utilizando?